# Javascript equivalent of http-equiv redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, meta-tags, http-equiv

What is the equivalent of these two meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://www.example.com/">

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35; URL=http://www.example.com/">
```

In JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a refresh you can use `window.location.reload()`.

If you need it to fire after 35 seconds use `setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 35000);`

To redirect to another page you can use either `window.location.replace('http://www.example.com')` to make sure the browser Back button skips the previous page, or `window.location = 'http://www.example.com'` to preserve the browser history.